# how to map xml element to bean property by an attribute and not by its name using betwixt?

Tags: xml, mapping, javabeans

the xml contains:
<rc ix="attr1">value1</rc>
<rc ix="attr2">value2</rc>

and the bean has 2 properties:
String prop1;
String prop2;

Does anyone know how can i map this in a .betwixt file?
Also i can only use betwixt...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<class name="package.name.ClassName">
    <element name="rc">
        <attribute name="attr1" property="nameOfProperty1" />
        <element name="value" property="theFieldValue1MapsTo" />
    </element>
</class>
```

Something in that sense. Betwixt has a nasty habit of not warning you about errors. To ensure you get the debug log set the log level on betwixt to `TRACE` or `INFO`.

Furthermore you must ensure all properties/attributes have `public` getters and setters with no side-effects. If they are `protected` or anything less visible, they will simply be ignored.

The naming convention for the getters and setters is the standard Java convention. In other words boolean getters/setters are allowed to be called `isSomeBooleanValue` and `setSomeBooleanValue`.

Betwixt is very picky and has not been supported since '08 I think, if you can, switch to JAXB or similar.